# Libxml - replace xml value if particular conditions are met

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I have an incomplete Perl script with the following content:

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXSLT;

my $xml_mess = "
<activity>
<ref1></ref1>
<ref2>id_119604</ref2>
<ref3>id_342432</ref3>
</activity>";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml_mess_obj = $parser -> parse_string($xml_mess);
my $ref1 = $xml_mess_obj -> getDocumentElement -> findNodes("/activity/ref1") -> [0] -> to_literal(); 
my $ref2 = $xml_mess_obj -> getDocumentElement -> findNodes("/activity/ref2") -> [0] -> to_literal();
my $ref3 = $xml_mess_obj -> getDocumentElement -> findNodes("/activity/ref3") -> [0] -> to_literal();
```

I would like to parse the `$xml_mess` and make the following changes:

1. When `ref3` has a value, then I want `ref1` to have the same value.
2. When `ref3` does not have a value, then I want `ref1` to have the same value as `ref2`.

I have been searching for examples on how to do this with LibXML, but can't figure out how to conditionally update nodes.

Comment: Please ensure that your example code compiles.

Comment: Tip: `-> getDocumentElement` isn't necessary. Document elements provide `findNodes`

Comment: Tip: `-> findNodes(...) -> [0] -> to_literal()` can be replaced with `-> findvalue(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want. See the embedded comments for more detail.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_mess = '
<activity>
<ref1></ref1>
<ref2>id_119604</ref2>
<ref3>id_342432</ref3>
</activity>';

# Load the XML into a Document object
my $xml_mess_obj = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml_mess);

# Get an Element object for the <ref1> node.
my $ref1 = $xml_mess_obj->findnodes('//ref1')->[0];

# Get the text of the <ref2> and <ref3> nodes.
my $ref2_txt = $xml_mess_obj->findnodes('//ref2')->[0]->to_literal;
my $ref3_txt = $xml_mess_obj->findnodes('//ref3')->[0]->to_literal;

# Use appendText() to add text to the <ref1> node.
# Note: // is the 'defined-or' operator. It returns $ref3_txt if that
# is defined, otherwise it returns $ref2_txt.
$ref1->appendText($ref3_txt // $ref2_txt);

# Display the result.
say $xml_mess_obj->toString;
```